# After killing jar instance(kill <PID>) with shutdown hook process is not being killed

Tags: java

I have a Java program with an attached shutdown hook. I run it and after I kill the running process with `kill <PID>`. By doing this the shutdown hook got executed and the related threads stopped immediately. But the process is still running in the background. So what could be the problem here?

Process:

1. `javac InfiniteLoop.java`
2. `java InfiniteLoop`
3. For PID, `jps -ml | grep 'InfiniteLoop'`
4. kill `<PID>`

```
public class InfiniteLoop {

  static boolean isInfinte = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread myThread = new MyShutDownHook();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(myThread);
    while (isInfinte) {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      System.out.println("Loop is running");
    }
    System.out.println("Loop Exited");
    myThread.interrupt();
  }
}

class MyShutDownHook extends Thread {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    System.out.print("Got Kill Message so stopping application");
    InfiniteLoop.isInfinte = false;
    boolean currentLoopStatus = true;
while (currentLoopStatus) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.print("Got Intteruption");
        currentLoopStatus = false;        
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Child Thread Running");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop in your shutdown hook waiting for an interrupt?

Comment: If you remove the System.exit, you get an infinite loop and your application hangs. I'm really surprised that your main thread gets to the point of printing "Loop Exited" and interrupting the shutdown hook thread, I doubt there is any guarantee that happens.

Comment: The shutdown order is explained in the https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread) All of your other threads will be allowed to continue execution until all of your shutdown hooks have completed. Then system.halt will be used. You can avoid this with a sig term, eg. `kill -9 PID`.

Comment: But using kill -9 PID, you will not be able to call implemented shutdown hook.

Comment: @RevansiddhaWaghmare that was my point, kill -9 avoids the shutdown hooks, or letting any of the other threads continuing to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used **`System.exit(0)`** in your shutdown hook thread. Remove it shutdown hook so that the process would get terminated normally. Actually **`System.exit(0)`** itself calls shutdown internally so it could possible that code is in deadlock.